# Parsing Command Output in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to run a command that gives the following output and parse it:

```
[VDB VIEW]
[VDB] vhctest
        [BACKEND] domain.computername: ENABLED:RW:CONSISTENT
        [BACKEND] domain.computername: ENABLED:RW:CONSISTENT
        ...
```

I'm only interested in some key works, such as 'ENABLED' etc. I can't search just for ENABLED as I need to parse each line at a time.

This is my first script, and I want to know if anyone can help me?

EDIT:
I now have:

```
cmdout=`mycommand`

while read -r line
do
   #check for key words in $line
done < $cmdout
```

I thought this did what I wanted but it always seems to output the following right before the command output.

> ./myscript.sh: 29: cannot open ... : No such file

I don't want to write to a file to have to achieve this.

Here is the psudo code:

```
cmdout=`mycommand`

loop each line in $cmdout
   if line contains $1
       if line contains $2
            output 1
       else
            output 0
```

Comment: @Mr Shoubs - hmmm ... try `YOUR_COMMANDS | grep -e "YOUR_KEYWORD1\|YOUR_KEYWORD2\|..."` Or pipe the output into a file

Comment: Each keyword I am searching for is mutually exclusive - for example, I want to know what keyword each line contains. this will eventually be used with Nagios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error is that

```
done < $cmdout
```

thinks that the contents of `$cmdout` is a filename.

You can either do:

```
done <<< $cmdout
```

or

```
done <<EOF
$cmdout
EOF
```

or

```
done < <(mycommand)    # without using the variable at all
```

or

```
done <<< $(mycommand)
```

or

```
done <<EOF
$(mycommand)
EOF
```

or

```
mycommand | while
...
done
```

However, the last one creates a subshell and any variables set in the loop will be lost when the loop exits.

Answer (score 3):

["How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

["I set variables in a loop. Why do they suddenly disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: You can be, with piping or process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
if [ `echo $line|grep "$1" | wc -l` != 0 ]; then
    if [ `echo $line|grep "$2" | wc -l` != 0 ]; then
        echo "output 1"
    else
        echo "output 0"
    fi
fi

done
```

USAGE

```
$ cat in.txt | ./test.sh ENABLED  RW
output 1
output 1
```

This isn't the best solution, but its a word by word translation of what you want and should give you something to start with and add your own logic

Comment: `if echo "$line" | grep -q "$1"; then` - no need for backticks, brackets, `wc` or `!= 0`